# When are module scripts (<script type="module">) fetched and evaluated?

Tags: javascript, html

When exactly are [*module scripts* (`<script type="module">`)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#module-script) fetched and evaluated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the *Living Standard* for HTML (October 22, 2017.)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element):

> ### For [*module scripts*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#module-script),
>
> #### if the [`async` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-async) is present,
>
> then the [*module script*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#module-script) and all its dependencies will be **fetched [*in parallel*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#in-parallel) to parsing**, and the [*module script*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#module-script) will be **evaluated as soon as it is available** (potentially before parsing completes).
>
> #### Otherwise,
>
> the [*module script*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#module-script) and its dependencies will be **fetched [*in parallel*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#in-parallel) to parsing** and **evaluated when the page has finished parsing**. (The [`defer` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-defer) has no effect on [*module scripts*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#module-script).)

[image: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/images/asyncdefer.svg]